# "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have the following ajax call

```
var response = "";
//Ajax call to the DB server
var target_url = "http://SomeIP/db/*create_table*?token=1234qwer&table_name="+table_name+"&array_of_fields={"+final_fields+"}";
function hit_db(callback)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: target_url,
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: callback,
        });
}
hit_db(function(data){
    response = data;
    alert(response);
});
```

However `alert(reponse)` shows `undefined` when the **correct output** should be `ERROR table already exists`

However, when I check on my dev. tools I see the following

[image]

and If I click on the link of the Uncaught SyntaxError it takes me to this page where the **correct output** is displayed

[image]

Why is the correct output I want in that Unexpected Identifier but I get undefined `alert(response)` ? Any possible fixes?

EDIT------

Here's some simplified code and the response

```
function hit_db(callback)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: target_url,
        type: 'GET',
        success: callback,
        });
}
hit_db(function(data){
    response = data;
    console.log(response);
});
```

[image]

---Network tab
[image]
[image]

Thank you!!

Comment: Sorry i changed my question last minute. I updated to my latest coded. The screenshot is the exact response I get when i check my dev tools. But when I alert(response) I get undefined

Comment: Also would you mind editing out the IP in your comment please? I just want to eliminate the chance of people trolling with my server hehehe

Comment: what looks to be the issue is that the server does not respond with JSONP - can you show an exact example of the response you get? Are you sure you are responding with JSONP not just JSON? or perhaps the JSONP is invalid (it has a syntax error in it, like the error message states)

Comment: I eliminated the jsonp to see if it would change anything but the result is still the same. Its driving me crazy because I dont know where to look for the syntax error

Comment: look in the response in the browser developer tools network tab - does it look valid?

Comment: I just checked the network tab and the correct response is there. I just saw that the `content-type` of the response headers is `text/html charset=utf-8` does that impact anything? How could I properly catch that?

Comment: So, you use JSONP because JSON gives you CORS errors - but JSONP isn't JSON, it's JSONP ... hence the syntax error - but as you've shown absolutely NOTHING about the response data, only claiming "it is correct", then it's hard to help. The response data is **not** correct for JSONP, that's why you have a syntax error, because JSONP isn't JSON, but I'm guessing you haven't sent JSONP from the server at all'

Comment: I apologize :( I should have provided screenshots sooner and I really do appreciate the time you're taking to help. I have provided screenshots of my network tab and I took out JSONP out of my code but I still get the same results

Comment: So without data type jsonp you still get a syntax error?

Comment: No, now I just get an `undefined` alert

Comment: that's due to the CORS error

Comment: Even though I get the desired output in the network tab? I put on my last screenshot

Comment: yes - the developer tools show the response - but javascript can not access the response due to lack of CORS headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you pls edit the code to a simple ajax call and check the console what it responds. Because if it works simply on a browser, i expect it to be a usual get request.

```
function hit_db()
{

$.ajax({
  url: target_url,
}).done(function(resp) {
  console.log(resp)
});

}
hit_db();
```

Edit: The issue was due to cross domain request. You will have to add 'Alloww-cross-orgin-request':* to your server response or you can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) to by pass it in your browser. If bypassing it in your browser is not an option i would say you will need to read about the different condition checks for cross origin checks done by browser in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: I have added the edit with the simplified code

Comment: And what do you see in console log??

Comment: The console is empty. Nothing is logged

Comment: Can you verify in the network tab that your api call has been requested? And if there is an error, pls paste it here,also confirm that the request was made in the correct url

Comment: Yes, I confirmed that is the correct URL with Postman which returns the correct output. And there are no errors in the network tab

Comment: Not the postman, when you run this code, you can see this api call in your browser developer tools's network tab. I was referring to that entry.Please verrify that the api call was made to correct url and whther there is any error there.

Comment: I just checked the network tab and the correct response is there. I just saw that the content-type of the response headers are `text/html charset=utf-8` does that impact anything?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171946/discussion-between-rohith-murali-and-net30).

Answer (score -2):

CORS   You can search CORS related content